# Installing .NET Framework

Tags: .net, installation, advanced-installer

I'm currently updating our software installer and have a few questions about getting the .NET framework installed.

1. What are the installer(s) (.exe or .msi) required to install .NET 2.0 SP2?
2. What are the installer(s) (.exe or .msi) required to install .NET 3.5 SP1?

Microsoft's download pages are slightly ambiguous. I belive I need [.Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5B2C0358-915B-4EB5-9B1D-10E506DA9D0F&displaylang=en) and Microsoft [.NET Framework 3.5 Service pack 1 (Full Package)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=d0e5dea7-ac26-4ad7-b68c-fe5076bba986&displaylang=en).

We need the .NET 2.0 SP2 for windows 2000; .NET 3.5 SP1 is for Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista x86 & x64, Windows Server 2008 x86 & x64 and Windows 7 x86 & x64.

These are to be run from Advanced Installer as software prerequisits. .NET 3.5 must support both x86 and x64 operating systems.

Comment: You 2.0 refernce is wrong, the Compact Framework is for windows mobile not for desktop windows. (Can't, off hand, find the right package hence comment not answer!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .NET 3.5 SP1 Full package is sufficient for everything* (as long as you have Windows Installer 3.1 or later installed), and requires no extra download or internet connection.

You do not need the compact framework.

If you only require .NET 2.0 SP2, you can download it [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/6/e/c6e88215-0178-4c6c-b5f3-158ff77b1f38/NetFx20SP2_x86.exe).

*** This includes all the latest SP's for .NET 2 and 3.

Comment: The compact framework thing was a mistake, has been edited. We have to support Windows 2000 with .NET 2.0, .NET 3.5 is for SQL 2008 which goes on everything above windows 2000.

Comment: @Stevo3000: If you have 'legacy' .NET 1.0/1.1 apps, you need to donwload those Framework Redistributable Packages separately.

Comment: @o.k.w - The question is about .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5, if it was about 1.0/1.1 it would be mentioned!

Comment: @leppie - It's a shame the 3.5 installer doesn't gracefully install 2.0 SP2 onto windows 2000. Cheers for the confirmation. +1